# Removing non-numeric values from a string and replace spaces with colon

Tags: javascript

I have a string with me to remove ONLY non-numeric and replace the spaces with colon to get my Timestamp.

This is the approach I followed to get my answer, but my question is are there any better approach to get this answer in Javascript?

```js
const string = '00h 01m 30s'

console.log(string.replace(/\D/g,' ').trim().replaceAll('  ', ':'));
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "better approach". If you want some kind of recommendation on the most efficient practices, you can visit [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that @skara9. Apologies and thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to match numbers, then join with a colon.

```js
const string = '00h 01m 30s'

console.log(string.match(/\d+/g).join(':'));
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this, but the only concern is this might not work if my string is empty unless I add a conditional check.

Comment: @user2824374 then add the check - `string.match(/\d+/g)?.join(':') || ''`